# Playing back to a microphone [java]

Tags: java, audio, playback, microphone

I want to write a java application that allows me to play back clips from my pc into the microphone.

For example:

I'm playing an ego shooter. After a long and tidious match I win the round. 
Then I press d - u - n, my application loads 'Darude - Sandstorm' from my harddrive, streams it into the microphone and everyone has a good laugh.

For catching the key input I know what to do, but for microphone? No, my friend. Maybe you can help me?

Comment: the microphone is usually used for input, not output

Comment: Usually it is then output into another application though.
Is 'artifical input' more to your liking?

Comment: ok, i get what you're doing. the idea is to use another device (which would actually be you application) as input. I have no idea how to do that, though.